# Execute bower update from ANT task

Tags: java, javascript, bash, ant, bower

i want to create an ANT Task that permit to execute bower update in my project.

I've written this target:

```
    <target name="update-static-web-dependecy" description="Update static web dependency">
        <exec dir="${static-web.dir}" executable="/usr/local/bin/bower">
            <arg  value="update"/>
        </exec>
    </target>
```

But when i'm going to run it i get this error :

> env: node: No such file or directory
>
> Result: 127

In my OS Bower is installed correctly with the arg -g and if i launch it from the shell it works well.

Can someone help me?

Regards,
Lorenzo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll take a guess that you could resolve by specifying the path to node in an `env` element in your `exec` block. Something like this

```
<property name="node.dir" value="/usr/local/bin"/>

<exec dir="${static-web.dir}" executable="/usr/local/bin/bower">
    <env key="PATH" value="${env.PATH}:${node.dir}"/>
    <arg value="update"/>
</exec>
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone wanting to do this in Phing, it's a little bit less involved, but the Ant answer might throw you. You can do it all in one go if you know where bower is:

```
<exec command="/usr/bin/bower install" dir="${dirs.httpdocs}" />
```

If you're doing something generic, you can check for the existence of bower.json first:

```
<!-- bower exists -->
<property name="bowerExists" value="false" />
<exec command="if [ -f '${dirs.httpdocs}/bower.json' ]; then echo 'true'; else echo 'false'; fi;" 
      outputProperty="bowerExists" />
<if>
    <equals arg1="${bowerExists}" arg2="true" />
    <then>
        <echo>Installing Bower Packages</echo>
        <exec command="/usr/bin/bower install" dir="${dirs.httpdocs}" />
    </then>
</if>
```

Source: http://www.szabogabor.net/how-to-check-in-phing-if-a-file-or-directory-exists/

Comment: If you run in to trouble set the `outputProperty` attribute of exec and echo it afterwards (that's how I solved it).